# can hydrogen stay frozen in vacuum?

Tags: thermodynamics, hydrogen, freezing, phase-diagram

I've look into the hydrogen state diagram, and it seems that it can be frozen under pressure.

> **Question:** Does this mean that hydrogen cannot be kept frozen in a vacuum chamber?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

yes, hydrogen (and anything) evaporates/sublimes in vacuum